# How to create an Exchange format email address for an external recipient?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I understand that email addresses used by Exchange server of this format are called X500 addresses:

> IMCFACX-_o=First+20Organization_ou=Exchange+20Administrative+20Group+20+28FYA8BOHF23SPDLT+29_cn=Recipients_cn=example@example.com

Is it possible to construct one of these addresses for a recipient who on a different Exchange server to me?

My aim is to send an email to such an address, which would tell my Exchange server to deliver it to a user on another Exchange server.